# PHP curl - correct way to send certificate?

Tags: php, curl

Im using a webservice that requires autentication it one cliente certificate sended by curl. I already have the certificate (.pem), the public key and the private key (.pem) extracted from a .pfx file.

Im sending then like this:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '_cert.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '_priKEY.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, '****');
```

But the WS always return the message that i need to send the cliente certificate. Whats is the correct way to send?

Other questions: Did i not need to send the public key file? and "keypasswd" is realy necessary?

Comment: You have the public and private key in the pem?  If you used a password on the key, you'd need keypasswd.

Comment: @Devon im sending the certificate and the private key separated, and also sending the pass too.

Comment: You wrote in the question: `the public key and the private key (.pem)` so I'm trying to understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @Devon what I could understand is that: the .pfx file is a certificate that contains the "certificate", the "public key" and the "private key". And to send them by curl you need to extract each into separated files (.pem files), and then you can send tem into the request.

Comment: @Devon Im not sure if this is the correct way, the WS keep returning that i need to send the certificate.

Comment: I don't think you should send the pub key in either pem.  You may want to define the absolute paths to both pems as well.  I wouldn't think they'd live in the same directory was your web script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using "**HTTP**", and to send the certificate on the request, i need to use "**HTTPS**".

Don't need to use "**CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE**" option when the format is **.pem**, because the .pem is already the default format.
The "**public key**", usualy, do not need to be sent, only the private key (when the certificate has one).

The "**CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD**" need to be used when the private key have some **passphrase**, other wise, don't use it.